# Linux, Eclipse, ARM toolchain and Codan errors

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, arm, codan

After whole week of Googling, asking questions here, etc. I set up my arm-none-eabi toolchain under Linux.
Finally!

My problem is (I really hope it's the last one!) I'm still getting Codan errors from Eclipse - it is pretty annoying. Those errors descriptions are for example:

- `Symbol 'stderr' could not be resolved`
- `Invalid arguments 'Candidates are: void sleep(?)`

I'm using Eclipse Luna for C/C++ developers. And code in editor is default one.

What should I do? Disable Codan? 'Teach' it to ignore things like that? If so, how can I do that?

[image: Isn't it annoying?]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here - [How to remove error "unresolved inclusion" for user defined path in eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801718/how-to-remove-error-unresolved-inclusion-for-user-defined-path-in-eclipse-ide) . After you do these steps you should rebuild your project (delete all outputs and compile everything), and also rebuild index by right clicking on the project and selecting Index > Rebuild.

This assumes that your project type is "Empty C++ Makefile project" with "Cross GCC" or "other toolchain".

EDIT: Not directly related to your question, just a hint at the end before you waste too much time for it like I did - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=352407

Comment: It definitely solved the problem - Thank you! My only wish is I don't have to set up all these things when creating new project. Is there a way other from writing Eclipse plugin to do that? And besides I'm from Poland too - Dzięki!

Comment: @Jacajack - you could try creating a "template project", which then could be copied + renamed (or imported and renamed or whatever way to duplicate the project). This way you would _probably_ have all the settings ready. Another option is to set these things globally ("globally" in Eclipse usually means "for Workspace") in Window > Preferences > C++ > Build > Settings, Discovery tab, but I personally wouldn't go that way - these settings are sometimes different across projects (especially the flags for "built-in" option) and in that case importing a project would _NOT_ transfer them. Proszę (;

Comment: I'll try that, for sure, but tomorrow. Anyway thanks for your help and time - you probably finished my arm-toolchain-problem-saga. =) BTW: I feel weird talking to you in English, though you are the same nationality as me... ;)

Comment: @Jacajack - That's how our globalized life goes on (; In case of problems you can always try to reach me via my personal page (with some info about ARM toolchains, ARM projects and so on) or via elektroda's forum - this time in Polish. Pozdrawiam! <:

Comment: Sure, thanks for information. I think I have seen your website.  Again thanks for help! Pozdrawiam!